# How do I pass an OpenGL context from Qt4?

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, qt4

I'm currently developing a game in the LeadWerks 2 engine and I've decided to use Qt4 as the GUI and window manager. What I want to do is create a Qt QGLWidget window and have the LeadWerks engine run inside of that.
There is some information of building a basic QGLWidget application [here](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/opengl-hellogl.html#qtlogo-class).

I'm really struggling to understand how to do this exactly. I can create a custom GL buffer within the LeadWerks engine and I believe what I need to do is give that buffer the GL context Qt created.
As for the LeadWerks side of things, the main thing I need to do is call a method called [CreateCustomBuffer](http://www.leadwerks.com/wiki/index.php?title=Buffers#CreateCustomBuffer) and pass it a few things:

**virtual void Buffer::CreateCustom( byte* getsize, byte* makecurrent)**

Creates and returns a new custom buffer. GetSize (defined as void _stdcall GetSize(int* width, int* height)) and MakeCurrent (defined as void _stdcall MakeCurrent(void)) are callback functions for the buffer. GetSize should return (by changing the value provided with a pointer) the size of the custum OpenGL buffer/context used. MakeCurrent should set the custom buffer as the current OpenGL context.

Comment: You linked to a forum that you have to register to view.

Comment: Is there some reason you want to try to combine Qt and LeadWerks, when neither is designed to be compatible with the other and they're both trying to do the same thing? What is Qt giving you that LeadWerks doesn't? Other windows? If so, why not use the LeadWerks window and just create some Qt windows on the side?

Comment: I will provide information out of the forum post I made.

LeadWerks is a rendering engine. It provides no GUI functionality. I intend to use Qt to perform that function.

Comment: I'm a bit confused, does the Leadwerks buffer object call the makecurrent function when it is ready to render?  In which case can't you just pass the `QGLWidget::makeCurrent()` method for it?

Comment: I'll be honest and say I've yet to completely understand the workflow, but I suspect you're right. The problem is that Leadwerks expects a (byte *) pointer to makeCurrent. I can't for the life of me work out how to do this without causing compile errors. I've asked another question on this over [here.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8373550/how-do-you-pass-a-non-static-function-as-a-callback)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> and MakeCurrent (defined as void _stdcall MakeCurrent(void)) are callback functions for the buffer

If I understand it correct, this callback will be called whenever LeadWerks wants the context to become active (it doesn't manage it itself then), similar the *getsize* callback is to obtain the size of the available window. So normally you'd use this to activate the context from another interface you've access for.

Unfortunately those callbacks don't allow for passing a pointer, which means, you can't pass the QGLWidget class instance pointer, so that you could delegate the call to a class member function. Not being able to pass user data to callbacks is a sign of bad API design, because it makes things hard, which would be easy otherwise.

There is a library called *ffcall* which provides a mechanism to get around this http://www.gnu.org/s/libffcall/callback.html

So you'd write a delegator function

```
void qglwidget_makecurrent(void *data, va_list alist)
{
    GQLWidget *widget = (QGLWidget*) data;
    widget->makeCurrent();
}

void qglwidget_getsize(void *data, va_list alist)
{
    int *widthptr, *heightptr;
    GQLWidget *widget = (QGLWidget*) data;
    va_start_ptr(alist, void);
    widthptr = va_arg_ptr(alist, int*);
    heightptr = va_arg_ptr(alist, int*);
    va_return_void(alist);
    *widthptr = widget->width();
    *heightptr = widget->height();
}
```

create callback wrappers (as in your QGLWidget derives class' constructor) as class member variables:

```
class MyGLWidget : QGLWidget {
/* ... */
    __TR_function qglwidget_makecurrent_callback;
    __TR_function qglwidget_getsize_callback;
}

MyGLWidget::MyGLWidget() {
    qglwidget_makecurrent_callback = alloc_callback(qglwidget_makecurrent, (void)this);
    qglwidget_getsize_callback = alloc_callback(qglwidget_makecurrent, (void*)this);
}
```

And those you can pass to LeadEngine:

```
buffer->CreateCustom((void(*)(int, int))qglwidget_getsize_callback, (void(*)(void))qglwidget_makecurrent_callback);
```

Comment: Thanks @datenwolf! Came out with a few errors however:
1. qglwidget_getsize() complains of a few things like va_start_ptr doesn't have enough arguments. va_return_type doesn't exist at all.
2. qglwidget_makecurrent_callback = alloc_callback(qglwidget_makecurrent, &qglwidget_instance) complains that qglwidget_instance doesn't exist. I tried replacing it with 'this' but qglwidget_makecurrent_callback doesn't like being assign a "__TR_function".

Any advice?

Comment: @S.Richmond: I was writing this in a hurry, so I missed a few things. See my changes.

Comment: Ah great. Last error is "a value of type "__TR_function" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "void (*)(void *, va_list list)"" on qglwidget_makecurrent_callback = alloc_callback(qglwidget_makecurrent, (void*)this);

Comment: You are seriously awesome! I'm so close! All the code appears to compile fine however I'm having linker problems with the lib. I'm using VC2010 and I'm getting LNK2001 errors for alloc_trampoline_r and __va_error1. I've linked in the callback.lib. I really hope this isn't some weird issue due to how old ffcallback is. I understand if you cannot help with this issue though. Any advice would be great.

Comment: @S.Richmond: I don't know if ffcall can be compiled with MSVC, after all it's a GNU library. (Also it's GPL). Makes me thinking that maybe I should someday write a LGPL licensed variant that also compiled with MSVC. Point is, I wanted to show, that it is possible to work around such bad APIs.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5586/discussion-between-s-richmond-and-datenwolf)