# Polymorphism: "A pointer to a bound function may only be used to call the function"

Tags: c++, opengl, pointers, glut

I'm separating my code into multiple files, but this is one thing I don't get.

In graphics.h:

```
...
class graphics {
public:
virtual void SizeMod(int w, int h);
...
}
```

In graphics.cpp:

```
...
void SizeMod(int w, int h) {
    //Code here.
}
...
```

In main.cpp:

```
...
graphics g;
...
int main (int argc, char **argv) {
    ...
    glutReshapeFunc(g.SizeMod);
    ...
}
```

Error:

```
error C3867: 'graphics::SizeMod': function call missing argument list; use &graphics::SizeMod to create a pointer to member
```

And so I did that:

```
...
graphics g;
...
int main (int argc, char **argv) {
    ...
    glutReshapeFunc(&graphics::SizeMod);
    ...
}
```

It still gives me an error (a different one).
Anything to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it won't work this way because `SizeMod` is a non-static class member method, so it needs `this` to be called on. You have to make `SizeMod` static.

Comment: It resulted me into a linking error.

    error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: static void __cdecl graphics::SizeMod(int,int)" (?SizeMod@graphics@@SAXHH@Z) referenced in function _main

Comment: Put a `graphics::` before `SizeMod` in line `void SizeMod(int w, int h)` in the cpp file.

Comment: @MM. Using a static member function is not guaranteed to work, because the calling convention may differ between C++ static member functions and C functions.

Comment: @Annonymousisnobody: See my answer for a nice solution that uses C++11 lambdas. It also explains why those things not "just mix".

Comment: @datenwolf: can't you force the required convention on a static method? I think you can.

Comment: @VioletGiraffe: No, because that is something deep down in the way the code generators work. C++ has no common ABI regarding the way, classes and class member functions look like on the binary level. With C++0x (the draft for C++11) it was actually tried to introduce such ABIs, but it never went through. So the reliable only way to do go about this is to have a wrapper outside of class scope, that's then compiled to the platform C ABI specs (which are still platform dependent, but at least every platform specifies a C ABI) and can be safely passed as a C callback.

Answer (score 1):

GLUT is a C API. `glutReshapeFunction` expects a callback to a function of the signature

```
void (int, int)
```

A C++ class member function, in your case graphics::SizeMod has the signature

```
graphics::void(int, int)
```

Now, there's no well defined C++ ABI that could be strictly translated into the commonplace C ABI, but for all practical means on most compilers the C++ signature from above looks like

```
void(graphics*, int, int)
```

if looked through the glasses of a C ABI.

This first `graphics*` parameter that's the implicit `this` pointer.

Which essentially means, when you pass that as callback to glutReshapeFunction it breaks because

- the types don't match
- and there's no way to somehow pass the instance along

***EDIT:** C++ lambdas don't work here as pointed out by Mike Dinsdale.*

---

Seriously, I'm really getting sick and tired of answering same question again, and again, and again, and again… It get's asked about 3 times a week.

Comment: There seem to be a few problems with your lambda code: `graphics gr()` is a MVP, you don't capture `gr` in the lambda and most seriously I don't think a lambda with captures can be converted into a function pointer (see e.g. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10997237/c11-lambdas-to-function-pointer))

Comment: @MikeDinsdale: Seems like you're right. Oh well, then back to the ffcall hacks I suggested in another answer also related to C++ member functions and callbacks: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8375672/524368